# How to Create a CaseFeed Under a Case?

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to display case with CaseFeeds and FeedComments on my console app support page. Now when users reply to a case I want to insert a CaseFeed from my application. As per the salesforce API docs, create or upsert is not supported on CaseFeed.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_casefeed.htm

Is there any way or work around to create a CaseFeed under Case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CaseFeed it like a view - a combination of all kinds of activities happening to the Case. 
It's bit similar to how Events and Tasks can be viewed together on a related list of Open Activities. Check the Type field to see what does it aggregate. It kind of makes sense for a view to be readonly.

You can imitate user posting to that Case instead - that'd be [`FeedItem`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) object.

```
insert new FeedItem(
    ParentId = '50070000006Rn5M', 
    Title='Some title', 
    Body = 'Some long text goes here', 
    Type='TextPost'
);
```

Comment: eyescream, you are the salesforce master blaster!!
thanks again for helping out.


btw can you directly insert an object like "insert new FeedItem()"  or its just an example?!!

Comment: If you don't care about the returned id - it'll work just fine. I don't use it too often - but I do use `delete [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE ...];` ;) But if you'll have more than one item it's better performance- & and governor limits-limits wise to insert 1 list or you'll run out of 150 DML statements / transaction.